# Antlr4 with C# - Parse text between matching symbols

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, antlr4

So I'm stuck, and nothing that I've tried has been working. I am trying to parse text between matching symbols, in this case, equal signs. I've gotten this to work in a different parser I was testing, but have since deleted. I tried to replicate what I could and my attempt is shown in the code below.

> **QUESTION**: How do I parse text between matching symbols, and/or what am I doing wrong with my current implementation.

Also, secondary to this, is there a way to get an output of all tokens found - their names and text values. I haven't searched for this yet so I'm sure I could find out, but I've been stuck on this first problem so I haven't been able to test options.

All of this is being run with Antlr4, Visual Studio 2013, and Windows 10.

TestGrammar.g4:

```
grammar TestGrammar;

start
    : title EOF
    ;

title
    : EQUALS title EQUALS
    | EQUALS ANY EQUALS // using NOTEQUALS didn't work either
    | EQUALS ' ' ANY ' ' EQUALS
    ;

EQUALS: '=' ;
ANY   : .+ ;
NOTEQUALS: ~[\r\n=]+ ;
```

Program.cs:

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] testStrings =
        {
            "= asdf =",
            "== asdf ==",
            "=== asdf ===",
            "=asdf=",
            "==asdf==",
            "===asdf==="
        };

        foreach (string s in testStrings)
        {
            AntlrInputStream inputStream = new AntlrInputStream(s);
            TestGrammarLexer wikiLexer = new TestGrammarLexer(inputStream);
            CommonTokenStream commonTokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(wikiLexer);
            TestGrammarParser wikiParser = new TestGrammarParser(commonTokenStream);
            TestGrammarParser.StartContext startContext = wikiParser.start();
            TestGrammarVisitor visitor = new TestGrammarVisitor();
            visitor.VisitStart(startContext);
        }
    }
}
```

TestGrammarVisitor.cs

```
class TestGrammarVisitor : TestGrammarBaseVisitor<object>
{
    public override object VisitStart([NotNull] TestGrammarParser.StartContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TestGrammarVisitor VisitStart");
        context.children.OfType<TerminalNodeImpl>().ToList().ForEach(child => Visit(child));
        return null;
    }

    private void Visit(TerminalNodeImpl node)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" Visit Symbol='{0}'", node.Symbol.Text);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
line 1:0 no viable alternative at input '=== asdf ==='
TestGrammarVisitor VisitStart
 Visit Symbol='<EOF>'
```

Comment: Did it work correctly for test1 and test2?

Comment: No it did not. Each test failed with the same result.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the spaces between = and string?

Comment: It did not. I tried all three test cases without the space. I also added a condition to the title which takes spaces into account, but that still failed.

Comment: Some observations: 1) you're only matching on single equal signs, but your test cases has more. 2) your `ANY` rule is too permissive, it matches anything (including equals signs!). 3) usually you would write your grammar ignoring whitespace not part of a token, you should probably do the same.

Comment: @JeffMercado I agree with 2 and 3, but I think his recursive title rule should be able to cope with nested equal signs no?

Comment: @JeffMercado I thought with how I had title set up - to recursively match itself if there were more than one equals signs - would work, but apparently not. I took that part out and added a plus to the EQUALS token ('='+), and also went back to using NOTEQUALS token as the middle section, and it now works! Now I just need to print out all the tokens somehow, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: @o_weisman: ah right, didn't notice that.

Comment: @CStrach: sorry, you were right there. I didn't notice it was recursive. What you had there was fine, it should even handle having equal counts on both ends.

Comment: That's what I thought. Hmm, maybe a bug with the Antlr4 and C#? Currently `EQUALS:'='+;` and `title:EQUALS NONEQUALS EQUALS;` works, but `EQUALS:'=';` and `title:EQUALS title EQUALS | EQUALS NONEQUALS EQUALS;` doesn't work.